# Comparison of dates and coloring text in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to compare dates and based on result i will have to color the text. So i tried this approach in my .vue file

```
        <p class="abc" :class="text-red": date1 > new Date()>
                  {{ date1 }}
```

But comparing condition is not working and text remains normal. Need some help on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try: `:class="{'text-red': date1 > new Date()}"`, or `:class="[date1 > new Date() ? 'text-red' : '']"`

Comment: also please show value of `date1`

Comment: The value of date1 on html shows as  2019-08-12

Comment: ok you need parse it into a real datetime object `new Date(date1) > new Date()` etc

Comment: yes current date shows Mon Jul 20 2020 19:22:40 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: np glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Try this.   `<p :class=" date1 > currentDate ? 'abc text-red' : 'abc'">{{ date1 }}`. And create a new variable called `currentDate` and set it to `new Date()` in the `created()` hook. This adds the class `text-red` when `date1 > currentDate` is true

Comment: Still i don't see this working. If i check {{ date1 > currentDate }} value i see true/false value getting displayed on html. But text is not getting colored.

Comment: Can you try it the edited way. The `abc` class you added may be preventing it from binding the new class. And check using inspector if the class is added to the element or not.